# Commenting or removing function calls at run time in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, runtime, function-calls

I'm copying files from source to destination and before copying files, i want to comment out function calls to a specific function in my script. How can i achieve this dynamically?

Ideally, i want to remove all the code that defines that function and all the calls to that function in my output file.

Either that, or something similar that we have in c# #if Debug?

So let's say this is my .ps1 file

```
Function Testfunction($param1){
   $result = $null
   Write-Host "This is test function"

   ##.. do something

   return $result
}

# ... some code ... 

$retVal = TestFunction

# ... more code ..
```

In above example, i want to remove/comment `$retVal = TestFunction` line. Even better i want to remove the definition of entire function alongwith the call.

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: If this is for purposes of debugging, PowerShell has debugging features built-in. Read the help topic `about_Debuggers` for more information.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out Bill, i will have a look at this!

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the script as a text file, and have a separate script which reads it using `Get-Content`, making the changes you require.

A better solution would be to use [a PowerShell module file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324(v=vs.85).aspx) which contains all of your function definitions, and is imported by your main script.

Editing a script as part of a copy/paste process strikes me as bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer gmsOulman! I considered using Get-Content but the thing is I want to get reference to all the occurences of those function calls and they could have different parameter sets so parsing the text and using regular expression to find out those references sounds a bit shaky in my opnion.  this is part of the build script that i am creating where i am moving files to a different folder and before i move that file(s), i want to remove some function call among other things.